# Extracting a string between a known string and the last character

Tags: sql, substring

I am trying to extract a string from between a known string and the last character.  I need to extract the two different dollar values, without the dollar sign.  I can get the first one but the second one keeps failing.  The problem is that the last character (period/decimal) exists several times in the data.  My query will correctly return the first amount of 109.99 but it returns a blank instead of the second amount of 89.99.  In addition, the dollar amounts can vary in character length so I can't use a fixed length to pull back the needed results.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @string = 'amount changed from $109.99 to $89.99.';

SELECT

CASE

WHEN CHARINDEX(' to ', @string) - (CHARINDEX('amount changed from $', @string) + LEN('amount changed from $')) < 0 THEN ''

ELSE SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX('amount changed from $', @string) + LEN('amount changed from $'), CHARINDEX(' to ', @string) - (CHARINDEX('amount changed from $', @string) + LEN('amount changed from $')))

END AS Amount_A,

CASE

WHEN CHARINDEX('.', @string) - (CHARINDEX(' to $', @string) + LEN(' to $')) < 0 THEN ''

ELSE SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX(' to $', @string) + LEN(' to $'), CHARINDEX('.', @string) - (CHARINDEX(' to $', @string) + LEN(' to $')))

END AS Amount_B;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: You have 3 dots (.) in the string so CHARINDEX('.', @string) - (CHARINDEX(' to $', @string) + LEN(' to $')) < 0 is always true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be elegant, but it works. See comments for explanation. reverse() helps a lot here.
FTR, you only need the two SELECTs here, the rest is simply for clarification.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @string = 'amount changed from $109.99 to $89.99.';
-- position of first $:
print charindex('$',@string)
-- position of first space after first $:
print charindex(' ', @string,charindex('$',@string))
-- the length between first $ and first space after first $:
print charindex(' ', @string, charindex('$',@string))-charindex('$',@string)-1
-- combine to select the first value:
select substring(@string,charindex('$',@string)+1, charindex(' ', @string, charindex('$',@string))-charindex('$',@string)-1)

-- the second $ sign (first $ after first $), plus 1 cause we don't want the $ itself:
print charindex('$',@string,charindex('$',@string)+1)+1
-- first $ from behind gives us the length of the string from second $ to the end:
print charindex('$',reverse(@string),0)-1
-- we don't want the last dot:
print charindex('$',reverse(@string),0)-2
-- combine to select the first value:
select substring(@string, charindex('$',@string,charindex('$',@string)+1)+1, charindex('$',reverse(@string),0)-2)
```

Comment: This was what I needed.  Thank you for the assist.